# Query for store data from array in multiple row with same id in postgres Nest.js

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, postgresql-9.3

I want a query for storing the data from an array in multiple rows with same id using typeorm postgres in nestjs. Note: I'm using one-to-many, many-to-one relationship for storing data. like a user can likes multiple books at a time so that I'm storing bookId in different rows with same userId in "Like" entity....so please help me to store data using query in typeorm. This help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.